# in iphone how to display the different tabs based on the user role

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, tabbar, role

I am working on a tab based application. The first tab contains the login button. After the user login, the user with small permissions can not see all the tabs. Is there a way to display tabs dynamically. I am using iOS 5.0 and storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated` ?

Here's code to restrict the visible tabs to only the first one when used in Apple's template code for a tab bar app.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)delegate.window.rootViewController;
FirstViewController *first = [[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:first] animated:NO];
```

Comment: sorry, can you be specific? Where can I invoke this method? I am using storyboard.

Comment: A storyboard makes it a bit harder but you could put a method into your app delegate to call from your button.  Since the delegate has a reference to a window, it can find the window's rootViewController, which should be your UITabBarController.  I'll edit my answer to show how it works in a simple app.